# Traslate nginx ingress rule with snippet to Istio

Tags: istio, nginx-ingress, istio-gateway

I have a nginx ingress controller and expose services with him, we planned change to istio to ingress traffic.

I have a ingress rule that contains snippet:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      location  ~* "^/" {
        proxy_pass "https://127.0.0.1";
        proxy_set_header Host $http_x_forwarded_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_connect_timeout 10s;
        proxy_send_timeout 120s;
        proxy_read_timeout 120s;
        client_max_body_size 300m;
      }

  name: foo
spec:
  ingressClassName: bar
  rules:
    - host: foo.bar
  tls:
  - hosts:
    -  foo.bar
```

This ingress copy http_x_forwarded_host to Host and send to nginx ingress.

There are any idea to convert this rule to istio?
Thanks.

Marco

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!,

It should be doable theoretically with below Istio building components:

1. Use regex based rewrites

`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` => [EnvoyFilter](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/envoy-filter/#EnvoyFilter-ApplyTo) to `HTTP_ROUTE` object

(example to be found on github [here](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/22290#issuecomment-774260856))

2. Forward 'X-Forwarded-For/X-Real-IP' headers to upstream host

If your application needs to know the real client IP address use the [Gateway Network Topology](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/configuration/traffic-management/network-topologies/#example-using-x-forwarded-for-capability-with-httpbin) (Alpha) feature.

**Remark:**

Attached by you the source manifest file seems to be suffering from a [known issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/6973) of latest nginx ingress controller, which reveals in following error on my env:

```
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "STDIN": admission webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io" denied the request:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error: exit status 1
2021/06/21 11:05:45 [emerg] 851#851: invalid number of arguments in "proxy_set_header" directive in /tmp/nginx-cfg063051389:453
nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "proxy_set_header" directive in /tmp/nginx-cfg063051389:453
nginx: configuration file /tmp/nginx-cfg063051389 test failed
```